# texture mapping different objects in three.js

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping, render-to-texture

We are studying on product designer project. Designer is ready.

I want to do 3d preview result with three.js.

How can we texture one side of phone case? or can we border texture mapping?

OBJLoader version:
http://www.shopilife.com/baskiburada/viewer/viewer_4.html

And some obj files cannot be textured. Error is "GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 2"
http://www.shopilife.com/baskiburada/viewer/viewer2.html

Comment: Your geometry needs UVs in faceVertexUvs[ 0 ] to avoid the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, regarding re-texturing the back vs. front of the phone case. The approach here is to seperate the UV coordinates on the model itself. This way you have two sets of materials/textures/UVs. Then during runtime you load them both using a `MeshFaceMaterial` to load the two materials in an array like so:

```
materialArray.push(THREE.BasicMeshMaterial({color: 0xff0000})); //use whatever Material type you'd like of course
materialArray.push(THREE.BasicMeshMaterial({color: 0x0000ff}));
var multipleMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materialArray);
phoneCaseMesh= new THREE.Mesh( geometry, multipleMaterial );
```

Then when you want to switch one out you would grab the mesh and change the mapping to the desired side something like:

```
phoneCaseMesh.material.materials[1].map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'newtexture.jpg' );
```

Second, regarding the Error on you second sample, WestLangley is correct the OBJ file has no UV coordinates to map to, so the index is out of bounds when you apply a texture. If you look at both OBJ files your iphone4.obj has `vt` entities while the untitled.obj is just `v` and `f`. Hope that helps